# How do I type check Date in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, firefox-addon-webextensions, typescript3.0

`instanceof Date === true` does not seem to satisfy TypeScript 3.4.5's control flow based type analysis. In the code below, TypeScript will complain that the value I am returning is not a Date even after I have checked that it is indeed a Date.

```js
async function testFunction(): Promise<Date> {
    const {testDate}: {testDate: Date | string} = await browser.storage.local.get({testDate: new Date()});

    if (testDate instanceof Date === true) {
        // typescript@3.4.5 will complain:
        // Type 'string | Date' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
        //   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
        return testDate;
    } else if (typeof testDate === "string") {
        return new Date(testDate);
    }
}
```

I could change the troubled line to `return testDate as Date` but that feels like I am not doing the correct thing.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is not your Typescript version but the comparison. Can you try it without `=== true`?

```js
if (testDate instanceof Date) {
    return testDate;
}
```

Comment: Even though it's redundant, do you have any valid argument on why it would be the issue ?

Comment: I think it has to do with the way how the control flow based type analysis works. Maybe the compiler only recognises it if it is just `if(x instanceof y)` and thinks `if(x instanceof y === true)` is just a normal comparison.

Comment: Agreed. This seems like a bug in the TypeScript compiler.